# Dell Blades or C-Series Rack servers for datacenter virtualization project

Tags: dell, vmware-vsphere, datacenter, blade-server

We have customers infrastructure hosted on physical HP boxes across several racks and finally we are planning to migrate them to Vsphere.Data is stored on NFS SAN.It was suggested to use c-Series Dell servers for hypervisors.
  In the past I have been involved in projects that used blades for virtualization and using c-Series feels like a unusual choice for me.
I am trying to figure out what are the pros and cons of using blades or c-Series in our scenario.Does anyone has experience with c-Series and Vsphere deployments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its probably fair to say that the C-series allows higher concentration of hosts in a rack, but perhaps less resources per host, in particular, network connections might be limited compared to those possible on a blade like the m610, for example.

That might or might not be an issue for you, only you know the exact details of your requirements.

Comment: Not sure. Ehcek th new mico blades - quarter height. That is 32 (!) blades, 2 sockets each, in one center. Dell finally gets it.

Comment: @tomtom yes I like the Dell blades, we've had various models of Dell blade for quite a while and overall I like what they're doing now.

Comment: I am still to see Dell's answer to FlexFabric.I could not get a good answer from Dell sales rep on what they can suggest to replace  explosion of the cables at the back of the chassis.

Comment: That is a problem. The backs of the cabinets we've deployed blades into and maxed out the network connections into each blade look like party time at Cthulu's house.

Comment: ? Sorry? What about using some in chassis switches with 10gb going out, or an infiniband fabric? I fail to see how one could need more than a handfull of network cables PER CHASSIS ;)

Comment: We're using 2 10Gb connections per blade as it is @tomtom plus some 1Gb conections. Nobody's going to be replacing these with a mobile phone server any time soon ;-)

Comment: Ah? Infiniband has 40gigabit per cable ;) With 45ns (that is nano seconds) constant latency. 10G is SLOW like molass compared to that.

Comment: @tomtom agreed but we have infrastructure in our server rooms that is built around 10Gb links, we can't afford to add infiniband infrastructure too.